# What does $ \alpha $ in this context mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

As I'm trying to replicate a study as part of a Master's course, I am not able to grasp what $ \alpha $ means in the following context, taken from Haws and Bearden (2006):

> The responses were averaged to form an overall perceived price fairness measure ($\alpha =.93 $)

It can't be the significance level, can it? I assume it it is some statistical test. However, which?

For reference: Haws, K. L., & Bearden, W. O. (2006). Dynamic Pricing and Consumer Fairness Perceptions. Journal of Consumer Research, 33(3), 304–311.

Comment: It looks to me like the authors took the responses and averaged them. The result is an " overall perceived price fairness measure" with a value of $0.93$. They then use the symbol $\alpha$ to refer to this summary average.

Comment: Could you link the paper or at least provide full reference?

Comment: That was also my first thought. However, the means of the 12 individual subject groups range from $3.08$ to $5.49$, so the overall mean of all 12 groups can't be that low.

Comment: I've just added the full reference to the original post.

Comment: Most likely it is refering to a test reliability score like Cronbach's alpha. If you average several score then you have to make sure that the scores correlate, otherwise one would sum random scores resulting in an average of 0.

Comment: I agree that it would probability be a measure of reliability like Cronbach's alpha; especially since the text of the article explicitly mentions *reliability* at least twice. A pity the authors couldn't bother themselves to add enough information to make it explicit (a single word would have sufficed!) and that subsequently neither referees nor editor saw fit to ask for it.

Comment: Great work, guys. Thank you so much. If you post an answer, I'm happy to accept it.
For your information: Cronbach's Alpha in my replication study is 0,88, so pretty okay, I would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to an answer so that the question can be marked answered.

Most likely it is refering to a test reliability score like Cronbach's alpha. If you average several scores then you have to make sure that the scores correlate, otherwise one would sum random scores resulting in an average of 0. The reliability score reflects this correlation.